# Как реализовать отправку данных без jQuery?

Tags: javascript

Как реализовать отправку данных, например при регистрации, без библиотеки jQuery, на чистом JavaScript?

То есть сделать такой запрос:

```
$.post('/reg.php', {name:name}, function(result){});
```

но без jQuery.

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest вот отличная статья с примерами как это работает.

Comment: @Klimenkomud то есть вот изменить слово "плагин" на "библиотека" вы решили, а исправить название _jQuery_, которое в трёх местах было написано неправильно, - нет?

Comment: @Regent Да тут собственно и код можно отформатировать, при желании.

Answer (score 2):

Как то так:

```
fetch('/reg.php', {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({name})
}).then(result => { 
    // ...    
})
```

Или

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/reg.php', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {    
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        let result = xhr.responseText;
        // ...
    }
}
xhr.send(JSON.strigify({name}));
```

Answer (score -1):

Я кода-то так писал.
Форма (модальное окно) ссылается на сам свой файл php.

`self.location = '/reg.php?'+param1+param2+param3;`

Comment: Использование GET-запроса для создания и изменения данных вредно, не соответствует стандартам, создаёт проблемы с кэшированием и небезопасно из-за сохранения всей информации в истории браузера и логах сервера